# Private in class call parent class method

Tags: c#

A newbie question, I got the following C# code where there is a inner-class B that need to call a method on class A.

Please advise how.

```
class A
{
  void MethodA() {
  }

  class B {
    void MethodB {
      // Now method B need to call Method A above
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nested types don't automatically have an instance of their parent type; you would need something like:

```
class B {
    private readonly A a;
    public B(A a) { this.a = a; }
    void MethodB() { a.MethodA(); }
}
```

and instead of `new B()`, you would use `new B(this)`.

Answer (score 0):

Make object of A inside class B. And use it inside MethodB.

```
class B
{
    private A objectA;
    void MethodB()
    {
        objectA.MethodA();
    }
}
```

Initialize objectA before using. You can do this in constructor.